# How to fix Query params containing $ in retrofit

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2

I have a query parameter where it expects a $, when i have added $ with an escaped character it is translated to %24

```
@GET("/ghi/abc/def(FieldId={FieldId},ContentId={ContentId})")
fun getUserGroup(
    @Header("authorization") token: String
    ,@Path("FieldId") fieldId: Long,
     @Path("ContentId") contentId: Long
    , @Query("\$filter") filter: String
    , @Query("\$skip") skip: String
    , @Query("\$top") top: String
    , @Query("\$count") count: Boolean
```

/ghi/abc/def(FieldId=22206,ContentId=346488)?%24filter=contains(tolower(Value),tolower('qwerty'))&%24skip=0&$top=2&%24count=true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong in that.

> %24 is the Url encoded character for $ .

Some special characters are replaced with some other characters which is known as HTTP URL encoding.

Server knows it and decodes it will correctly handle the request.